# Python Math examples

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to debug line by line.

The following code calculates the number of cans needed to paint a given area of a wall.

```
def paint_calc(height, width, cover):
    area = math.ceil(height * width) / cover
    print(f"You'll need {area} cans of paint.")
```

The code does not provide a rounded up number, rather, it gives a floating point number. However, the code below returns an integer that is rounded up, so why do these not return the same answer?

```
def paint_calc(height, width, cover):
    area = height * width 
    num_of_cans = math.ceil(area / cover)
    print(f"You'll need {num_of_cans} cans of paint.")
```

Comment: In the first example, you first do rounding and then division. In the second example, you first do division and then rounding. Hence, the difference.

Comment: `/` is floating point division. In the first case you are rounding up then doing floating point division, later case you are doing the floating point division then doing the ceiling. Take example `height=2.3 width=1, cover=3.3` and do it on paper, it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can give an Integer Ceil Value because you can apply Ceil Function in your final calculation.

```
def paint_calc(height, width, cover):
    area = height * width 
    num_of_cans = math.ceil(area / cover)
    print(f"You'll need {num_of_cans} cans of paint.")
```

but this one didn't give an Integer because you can apply Ceil method on `(height * width).`

```
def paint_calc(height, width, cover):
    area = math.ceil(height * width) / cover
    print(f"You'll need {area} cans of paint.")
```

but if you expand your bracket a little more like this

```
area = math.ceil(height * width / cover)
```

instead of this

```
area = math.ceil(height * width) / cover
```

It can give you an Integer.

**NOTE:** In Math, Python uses `PEMDAS` ( Parentheses, Exponential, Multiply, Divide, Addition, Subtraction)

Answer (score 0):

The two code blocks are different.

In the first one `math.ceil(height * width)` gives an integer but then you are dividing it by another number `cover` (even if the cover is integer), thus giving a floating point number . That is how the division works in python.

You should also see integer division (e.g, `3//2` will give 1 (i.e, integer part of the answer)).

In the other case, you are putting everything inside the ceil function thus getting an integer as a result.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you have: `area = math.ceil(height * width) / cover` that mean:

1. First step `math.ceil(height * width)`
2. Second step dividing by `cover`
   "The problem" is the final division

Example 3/1 = 1.0

And in the second function you realize the operation and then apply the math.ceil and always round the result.